# Flutter: listen data from Bloc state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tabs in my app:

- news
- promotions
- shop

Also, I have blocs for fetching data for each tab (one bloc per tab). I want show tab only if I get a not empty list of data from bloc. How can I get access to this?

I push events while initState():

```
void _fetchData() {
context
  ..read<FeedBloc>().add(const FeedEvent.fetch(isFirstFetch: true))
  ..read<PromotionsBloc>().add(const PromotionsEvent.fetch(isFirstFetch: true))
  ..read<ShopBloc>().add(const ShopEvent.fetch(isFirstFetch: true));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [BlocBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) to check if data is not empty. You can try something like this:

```
BlocBuilder<FeedBloc, FeedBlocState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if(state.news == null || state.news!.isEmpty) return const SizedBox.shrink();
    
    return NewsTab();
  }
```

Comment: is BlocBuilder required for checking data? What about BlocListener?

Comment: For the situation you said it is required cause you wanna build the tab if data is not null, BlocListener is used when you wanna know the state and do something like navigate to another page or show a dialog, for example.